# brownian motion of 100 nm spherical particles in evenly spaced arrays

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, simulation

Generally looking for perspective from the computational experts. Question comes down to how tractable is the following problem. Let's say at time 0, I have a 2-D array of $N = 10$ spherical particles of diameter $D = 100$ nm (not touching, outer surfaces spaced evenly apart by, say, 1 particle of diameter $d= 100$ nm).  Allow a Brownian motion to start for all $N$ particles.

If two particles collide, I want the simulation to have them "stick" together, the resulting particle should have 2 times the mass of one particle and hence the program would have to adjust that particles diffusion etc. The question is: in what state does one find the $N$ particles (how many single particles, 2-particles cluster, 3 particles, etc) after the particles have largely escaped each others "diffusional fields".

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this as a function of the spacing the particles start from each other (0.5 diameters, 1,2, 3 diameters apart etc).

Have any such simulations been done, or is this stupidly intractable, etc. I am looking for some general directions on how to get this done.